# how to create a pipileine which will query a Mysql DB

Tags: mysql, jenkins, pipeline

I need to create a pipeline to execute a mysql query and email response the query should be sanitized first, like should be only select and on some particular tables only, if this makes sense???

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with setting a docker image at the pipeline stage.
You can check this example:

```
node {
    checkout scm
    /*
     * In order to communicate with the MySQL server, this Pipeline explicitly
     * maps the port (`3306`) to a known port on the host machine.
     */
    docker.image('mysql:5').withRun('-e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw" -p 3306:3306') { c ->
        /* Wait until mysql service is up */
        sh 'while ! mysqladmin ping -h0.0.0.0 --silent; do sleep 1; done'
        /* Run some tests which require MySQL */
        sh 'make check'
    }
}
```

You can check [this post](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/)